Show that $(I_1 +I_2)^e=I_1^e + I_2^e$.
Let $R$ and $S$ be two commutative rings with ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$. An extension of an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ defined by $I^e=(f(I))$ i.e., $I^e$ is the ideal generated by $f(I)$. Show that $$(I_1 +I_2)^e=I_1^e + I_2^e$$
By definition, $(I_1 +I_2)^e=\sum_{i=1}^n r(a_i+b_i)$ where $r\in R$, $a_i \in I_1$ and $b_i \in I_2$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n r(a_i+b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n ra_i+rb_i=\sum_{i=1}^n ra_i+\sum_{i=1}^n rb_i\in I_1^e +I_2^e$$
Conversely, let $\sum_{i=1}^n ra_i+\sum_{i=1}^n sb_i\in I_1^e +I_2^e$. Then,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n ra_i+\sum_{i=1}^n sb_i=\sum_{i=1}^n ra_i+ sb_i$$
How can I take them common paranthesis to have something $\sum_{i=1}^n r'(a_i+b_i)$?

I don't think $(I_1+I_2)^e$ has the form you say. If $x$ is in $(I_1+I_2)^e$, then $x$ is the $S$-linear combination of elements of the form $f(x_1),\cdots,f(x_k)$ where $x_1,\cdots,x_k$ are in $I_1+I_2$. When extending, you have to use the map $f$. This same issue shows up in the other direction; elements of $I_1^e+I_2^e$ look like $x+y$ where $x$ is an $S$-linear combination of things of the form $f(x_1),\cdots,f(x_k)$ where $x_1,\cdots,x_k$ are in $I_1$, and similarly for $y$.

$\sum_{i=1}^n r(a_i+b_i)$ is clearly an element in $R$, the source ring of the homomorphism. You should then realize that you must have mistaken some thing, because extension ideal is an ideal in the target ring.

FWIW there is also an abstract proof. This is not something you probably want or need to understand as your first proof of this statement, but it might be interesting to some readers.
Notice that the extension of ideals $I^e = \langle f(I) \rangle$ satisfies the fundamental relation
$$I^e \subseteq J \iff I \subseteq f^{-1}(J).$$
This is clear. In other words, the extension of ideals is left adjoint to the contraction (preimage) of ideals; since we are talking about partial orders this is called a Galois connection. And left adjoints preserve all colimits, so in our case it preserves all sums of ideals.
We may also repeat the proof in this special case (so that you can see that this doesn't depend on anything complicated): Let $(I_s)_{s \in S}$ be a family of ideals. Then for ideals $J$ of $S$ we have
$$\begin{align*} \textstyle (\sum_s I_s)^e  \subseteq J & \iff \textstyle \sum_s I_s \subseteq f^{-1} J \\ & \iff \forall s \, (I_s \subseteq f^{-1} J) \\ & \iff \forall s \, (I_s^e \subseteq J) \\ & \iff \textstyle \sum_s I_s^e \subseteq J,\end{align*}$$
and hence
$$\textstyle (\sum_s I_s)^e = \sum_s I_s^e.$$
You might wonder: why should we even care to choose this proof when we can just calculate with elements easily? The reason (at least, from my perspective) is that I want to be able to prove this kind of result also when no elements are available. Say, you want to prove the corresponding statement for ideal sheaves. Computing this with local sections is possible but awkward. The proof above however works in great generality, so that no additional work is required. This is basically the whole purpose of category theory, we want to recycle proofs as much as we can.

This is most easily done in the language of generating sets. Let $X_1$ be a generating set for $I_1$, and $X_2$ be a generating set of $I_2$. Then, $X=X_1\cup X_2$ generates $I_1+I_2$. Further, if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ with a generating set $Y$, then $f(Y) = \{ f(y) \mid  y \in Y\}$ is a generating set of $I^e$. You may want to prove these two facts!
To show $(I_1+I_2)^e = I_1^e + I_2^e$, it suffices to show they have a generating set in common. But, $f(X)$ generates $(I_1+I_2)^e$ and $f(X_1)\cup f(X_2)$ generates $I_1^e+I_2^e$. Since $f(X) = f(X_1\cup X_2) = f(X_1)\cup f(X_2)$, we are done.
